# Getting a Maybe instead of an Array's value

Tags: elm

New to elm here, and at first it's driving me absolutely crazy not knowing the ins and outs of this picky language (even after reading a sh**load about it because it's just so different and finicky...I guess that's the nature of a functional lang) so when you try doing a simple thing it's like pulling hair at first.

I am getting the following error:

```
The right side of (==) is causing a type mismatch.

29|             get 0 arrayOfValues == 'X'
                              ^^^
(==) is expecting the right side to be a:

    Maybe Char

But the right side is:

    Char

Hint: With operators like (==) I always check the left side first. If it seems
fine, I assume it is correct and check the right side. So the problem may be in
how the left and right arguments interact.
```

Test:

```
it "blah blah blah" <|
    let
        someArray =
            [ 'P', ' ' ]
    in
expect (MyModule.doSomething someArray 'P') to equal 1
```

**MyModule**

```
doSomething : List Char -> Char -> Int
doSomething arrayOfValues symbol =
    let
        grid =
            fromList arrayOfValues

        found =
            get 0 arrayOfValues == symbol
    in
    if found then
        1
    else
        0
```

Now I'm *assuming* but not sure, that it's getting Nothing or something when trying to pull the first value out of my array but not sure.  Maybe Char I assume is returning Nothing?  donno,  probably have other issues going on with it too.

I'd like to get the code above working, then refactor..I'm sure there's probably a more elegant way to code what I've coded above but first thing's first, fixing this error and understanding it better with the existing code.  The error message while nice isn't that obvious to me as to how and what to handle.  I have assumptions but not fully sure how to handle the behavior here of whatever is causing the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Array.get` returns a value wrapped in a `Maybe` because there might not be a value present at the specified index in the array. If you want to check whether the value at index 0 present *and* equal to `'X'`, you can compare to `Just 'X'`:

```
get 0 arrayOfValues == Just 'X'
```

Like the error message says, the compiler found that the left side of `==` is a `Maybe Char` and the right is `Char`. You need to convert one to another to use `==`. In this case, you probably want to change the right side as I suggested above.

Comment: It would be nice if the docs explained a little more than the syntax.  They don’t mention anything about it sending back a wrapped value

Comment: "Like the error message says, the compiler found that the left side of == is a Maybe Char and the right is Char".  Yep but if you haven't done elm, it's not that obvious what to do especially if you haven't used Just, Maybe and all that sh** yet and when you read it, it's not that obvious until you get real context into when you need to use it in real code.